# SharePoint Online Search reports and Usage Reports in Search got error "An unexpected error has occurred."

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, content-search-web-part

I am a Sharepoint Admin. In Admin Center, I go to SharePoint, more features, Search, when I go to open "Usage Reports" or Search Reports I got error "Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred." URL below.
company-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSearch
No other errors.
When click one 'Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation' I got 'Unfortunately, help seems to be broken...'
I googled the correlation ID, but found nothing.